# Scrolling not working inside div using Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

When I setup this middle div on a page, the situation is like this.

- Top Bar should be sticky and not move
- Middle should scroll as new content arrives or if user scrolls up or down
- Bottom Bar should remain sticky

I end up with a number of issues and when I fix one, another breaks. Also, at times depending on how I have the CSS setup, the top or bottom bars will overlap onto the right sidebar and I cannot figure out why. I know the code below seems crazy, but I did this to give someone the ability to actually work with what I see. the actual code is controlled by JavaScript so it isnt this painful normally.

I really cannot stress enough I am a backend guy and I have been at this for 3 days now going crazy trying to learn this on my own.

````
    <div class="flex-1 flex overflow-hidden">
        <div class="w-full">
            <div class="sm:hidden">
                <label for="tabs" class="sr-only">Select a tab</label>
                <select id="tabs" name="tabs" class="block w-full  focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 border-gray-300">
                    <option>Smoking &amp; Cigars</option>
                    <option>Darkroom</option>
                    <option>Humiliation</option>
                    <option>Financial Domination</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden sm:block sticky top-0 z-10">
                <div class="border-b border-gray-200">
                    <nav class="-mb-px flex dark:bg-gray-900" aria-label="Tabs">
                        <a href="#" class="border-indigo-500 text-indigo-600 w-1/4 py-4 px-1 text-center border-b-2 font-medium text-sm" aria-current="page">Smoking &amp; Cigars</a>
                        <a href="#" class="border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 w-1/4 py-4 px-1 text-center border-b-2 font-medium text-sm">Darkroom</a>
                        <a href="#" class="border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 w-1/4 py-4 px-1 text-center border-b-2 font-medium text-sm">Humiliation</a>
                        <a href="#" class="border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 w-1/4 py-4 px-1 text-center border-b-2 font-medium text-sm">Financial Domination</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <section class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 min-w-0 flex-1 h-auto flex flex-col lg:order-last">
                <div>
                    <ul class="divide-y divide-gray-200">
                        <li class="bg-white py-4 px-4">
                            <div class="flex space-x-3">
                                <img class="h-6 w-6 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                                    <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
                                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                            <h3 class="text-sm font-medium">Username</h3>
                                            <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">1h</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                            <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">Deployed Workcation (2d89f0c8 in master) to production</p>
                                            <p class="text-sm bg-blue-500 p-1 rounded text-gray-50"></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section aria-labelledby="chat-footer" class="h-auto w-full sticky shadow-2xl bg-gradient-to-br from-gray-100 to-gray-300 dark:from-gray-900 dark:to-gray-900 border-l dark:border-gray-800 border-gray-200 bottom-0 min-w-full flex-1 flex flex-col lg:order-last">
                    <div>
                        <span class="pl-10 pt-2 relative z-0 inline-flex shadow-sm rounded-md">
                            <button type="button" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-1 rounded-l-md border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                                <svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10 20l4-16m4 4l4 4-4 4M6 16l-4-4 4-4"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-1 border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500"> YouTube </button>
                            <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-1 border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                                <svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4a4 4 0 100 8 4 4 0 000-8zM2 8a6 6 0 1110.89 3.476l4.817 4.817a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4.816-4.816A6 6 0 012 8z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-1 border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                                <svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 16v1a3 3 0 003 3h10a3 3 0 003-3v-1m-4-8l-4-4m0 0L8 8m4-4v12"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-1 border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                                <svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M8 11V7a4 4 0 118 0m-4 8v2m-6 4h12a2 2 0 002-2v-6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v6a2 2 0 002 2z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                            <div class="relative inline-block text-left">
                                <div>
                                    <button id="headlessui-menu-button-1" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 rounded-r-md border border-gray-300 bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-800 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500"> Send Option 
                                        <svg
                                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="-mr-1 ml-2 h-5 w-5">
                                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <!---->
                            </div>
                        </span>
                        <div class="pr-10 pl-10 pb-5  h-full mt-1 flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
                            <div class="relative flex items-stretch flex-grow focus-within:z-10">
                                <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 pl-3 flex items-center pointer-events-none">
                                    <svg
                                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400">
                                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 4.354a4 4 0 110 5.292M15 21H3v-1a6 6 0 0112 0v1zm0 0h6v-1a6 6 0 00-9-5.197M13 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full rounded-none rounded-l-md pl-10 sm:text-sm border-gray-300" placeholder="Type your message...">
                                </div>
                                <button id="switchTheme" class="-ml-px bg-indigo-700 relative inline-flex items-center space-x-2 px-4 py-1 border border-gray-300 text-sm font-medium rounded-r-md text-gray-700 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                                    <svg
                                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-50">
                                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10.325 4.317c.426-1.756 2.924-1.756 3.35 0a1.724 1.724 0 002.573 1.066c1.543-.94 3.31.826 2.37 2.37a1.724 1.724 0 001.065 2.572c1.756.426 1.756 2.924 0 3.35a1.724 1.724 0 00-1.066 2.573c.94 1.543-.826 3.31-2.37 2.37a1.724 1.724 0 00-2.572 1.065c-.426 1.756-2.924 1.756-3.35 0a1.724 1.724 0 00-2.573-1.066c-1.543.94-3.31-.826-2.37-2.37a1.724 1.724 0 00-1.065-2.572c-1.756-.426-1.756-2.924 0-3.35a1.724 1.724 0 001.066-2.573c-.94-1.543.826-3.31 2.37-2.37.996.608 2.296.07 2.572-1.065z"></path>
                                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 12a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                    <span class="text-gray-50">Send</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- User List (hidden on smaller screens) -->
            <aside class="w-80 bg-gray-100 shadow-2xl border-l border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-800 overflow-y-auto lg:block">
                <div class="sticky top-0 bg-white z-10">
                    <!--User List Filter -->
                    <div class="sticky top-0 bg-white z-10">
                        <nav class="relative z-0 shadow flex divide-x divide-gray-200 dark:divide-gray-800" aria-label="UserLists">
                            <a href="#" class="text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-50 group relative min-w-0 flex-1 overflow-hidden bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 py-4 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-center hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-50 focus:z-10" aria-current="page">
                                <span>All</span>
                                <span aria-hidden="true" class="bg-indigo-500 absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0 h-0.5"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:dark:text-gray-50 group relative min-w-0 flex-1 overflow-hidden bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 py-4 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-center hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-50 focus:z-10">
                                <span>Watching</span>
                                <span aria-hidden="true" class="bg-transparent absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0 h-0.5"></span>
                            </a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <span class="relative z-0 inline-flex justify-evenly w-full shadow-sm rounded-md">
                            <button type="button" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-6 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-indigo-600  dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                                <svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-50 dark:text-gray-50">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M3 4h13M3 8h9m-9 4h6m4 0l4-4m0 0l4 4m-4-4v12"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white  dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                                <svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M3 4h13M3 8h9m-9 4h9m5-4v12m0 0l-4-4m4 4l4-4"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white  dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                                <svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 10l4.553-2.276A1 1 0 0121 8.618v6.764a1 1 0 01-1.447.894L15 14M5 18h8a2 2 0 002-2V8a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v8a2 2 0 002 2z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white  dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                                <svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 4.354a4 4 0 110 5.292M15 21H3v-1a6 6 0 0112 0v1zm0 0h6v-1a6 6 0 00-9-5.197M13 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-6 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white  dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                                <svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 6V4m0 2a2 2 0 100 4m0-4a2 2 0 110 4m-6 8a2 2 0 100-4m0 4a2 2 0 110-4m0 4v2m0-6V4m6 6v10m6-2a2 2 0 100-4m0 4a2 2 0 110-4m0 4v2m0-6V4"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--User List Users -->
                <ul class="flex-1 divide-y divide-gray-200 dark:divide-gray-800 overflow-y-auto dark:bg-gray-900">
                    <li>
                        <div class="relative group py-6 px-5 flex items-center">
                            <a href="#" class="-m-1 flex-1 block p-1">
                                <div class="absolute inset-0 group-hover:bg-gray-50" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                                <div class="flex-1 flex items-center min-w-0 relative">
                                    <span class="flex-shrink-0 inline-block relative">
                                        <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80" alt="">
                                            <span class="bg-green-400 absolute top-0 right-0 block h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        </span>
                                        <div class="ml-4 truncate">
                                            <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-50 truncate">Leslie Alexander</p>
                                            <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 truncate">lesliealexander</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <div class="ml-2 flex-shrink-0 relative inline-block text-left">
                                    <button id="headlessui-menu-button-35" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" class="group relative w-14 h-8 bg-white rounded-full inline-flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                                        <span class="sr-only">Open options menu</span>
                                        <span class="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full rounded-full">
                                            <svg
                                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500">
                                                <path d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z"></path>
                                            </svg>
                                        </span>
                                    </button>
                                    <!---->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
            </div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

At the very top of the code is a "overflow-hidden" which causes all child divs not to scroll. Once I changed that to scroll and made sure the top and bottom were set to sticky, it worked fine.